# Count variable in outer scope one up if text is found in DOM

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I want to check if a text/comment at a special location is like expected. If so, I want to count up itemFound by 1. The problem is, that I can't bring the variable to the outer scope.
(later I want to search many locations for this element)

```
let itemFound = 0;
cy.xpath('//table/div/span').then((item) => {
    let comment = item.text().trim();
    if (comment == "myuniquecomment")
    {
        itemFound += 1;
    }
    cy.log(itemFound)     // okay 
})

cy.log(itemFound)  // not okay
```

Comment: The problem isn't scope, it's *timing*. You're looking at the value of the variable before the promise settles. You should look at it *after*

Comment: Take a look at [Visualize cypress command queue](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/visualize-cypress-command-queue/) to see the order of execution for your code.

Comment: Essentially `cy.then(() => cy.log(itemFound))` will work because it's enqueuing the log command after previous commands have run.

Comment: To think of Cypress code as promises is incorrect, it's better to understand that the command queue runs ***after*** the test block has run.

Comment: @Fody Your second comment is the solution!

Comment: @Fody So the duplicate link is wrong? How to inform T.J. Crowder? @t-j-crowder?

Comment: The duplicate link is frankly monstrous, I don't know how you are supposed to apply it. The broad principle is the same, but the resolution is different. This Cypress question has been asked a lot of times before, but tracking them down is quite difficult even when I answered them myself. I just thought you deserved a better response.